# How to call an undeployed contract from a solidity code that only implements a constructor

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, remix, erc-777

I've two contracts, and I want to call a contract from another contract. I've two ways to do it, as described [here](https://solidity-by-example.org/calling-contract/)
but, my case is different, the callee contract only implements the constructor inside which I'm assigning the tokens. So, my question is how can I do this?

Token.sol

```
contract Atoken777 is ERC777 {

  string public constant tokenName = "TokenFare";
  string public constant tokenSymbol = "P2PRS";
  uint256 public constant initialTokenSupply = 2500;

  mapping(address => uint256) public holderBalances;

  constructor(bytes memory userData ,address toAssignHere, address[] memory defaultOperators)
    ERC777(tokenName, tokenSymbol, defaultOperators){
      _mint(toAssignHere, initialTokenSupply, userData, "");
  }
  
}
```

DriverFactory.sol

```
contract DriverFactory {

  address[] public deployedDrivers;

  function createDrivers() public {
    Driver createNewDriver =  new Driver(msg.sender);
    //TokenInterface token = TokenInterface(_parameters)
    deployedDrivers.push(address(createNewDriver));
  }

  function getAllRegisteredDrivers() public view returns(address[] memory) {
    return deployedDrivers;
  }

}
```

What's the point of making an interface of a contract that only implements a constructor, but still, I do want to call this token contract?

Answer (score 1):

`Atoken777` doesnt only have a constructor here, it's also a child of ERC777, meaning it includes all of its methods as well. If you want to interact with it, use an interface for ERC777